# Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException Bad notification posted from package

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have an application on the Play Store,Recently I've been received a lot of crash on ActivityThread.java with the message

Fatal Exception

> Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException
>   Bad notification posted from package XXX: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=XXX user=UserHandle{0} id=1 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=XXX/0x1090065 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 kind=[null]))

```
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,"1").setContentTitle("Prayer Time Alert!").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_logo)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setDeleteIntent(createOnDismissedIntent(this,1))
            .setContentText(msg);


    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());

private PendingIntent createOnDismissedIntent(Context context, int notificationId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationDismissedReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.my.app.notificationId", notificationId);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    notificationId, intent, 0);
    return pendingIntent;

}
public class NotificationDismissedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int notificationId = intent.getExtras().getInt("com.my.app.notificationId");
  /* Your code to handle the event here */
    if (Global.mPlayer != null) {
        Global.mPlayer.stop();
    }
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(notificationId);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to-:

```
alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
```

To-:

```
alarmNotificationManager.notify(0, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
```

The id should be same as in case of pending intent and in Notification Manager.